# Validate token after redirection from forgot password email link

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, passwords

I am currently working on `forgot` password API and `reset` password API in Laravel 5.5. Currently, I have no idea how to validate password after I click on the link in email and show the **reset password** and **confirm password**.

I have sent the token along with the email. The thing is before asking for password and confirm password I need to first verify the token if it is valid token from the table and its expiry date. Can anyone guide me some way around how to do this?

**Here's my forgot password.**

```
public function forgotPasswordApi(Request $request){
    $rawPostData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    if(isset($rawPostData['email'])) {
        $user = UserModel::where('email',$rawPostData['email'])->first();
        $token=TokenModel::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
        if($user){
            if(!$token){
                $token=new TokenModel;
                $token->token=md5(uniqid().$token->id);
                $token->token_code = TokenModel::$forgotPasswordToken;
                $token->expire_date = date("F j, Y, H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hour'));
                $token->user_id=$user->id;
                $token->save();
            }
            Mail::raw($user, function ($message) use ($user){
                 $token=TokenModel::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
                 $message->to($user['email'])
                 ->subject('Forgot Password Subject')
                 ->setBody('To reset password. Click on the following URL. '.url('/password/reset/?token=').$token->token);
            });
        }
        $data['status'] = 'success';
        $data['msg'] = $token;
    }else{
        $data['status']='fail';
        $data['msg']='Missing required paramater';
    }
    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

**Note:** Mail with the reset link was successfully send but I didn't get idea to go through reset password with that link.

**Email Sample**

```
To reset password. Click on the following URL.
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/password/reset?token=fca709c8a8ef5ff61aa5bb73e475c602
```

Here's my **incomplete reset password**

```
    public function resetPasswordApi(Request $request){

    if(Input::has('token'))
    {
        $token_input = Input::get('token');

        $token = DB::tables('tokens')
        ->where('token',$token_input)
        ->where('expire_date','>=',Carbon::now()->subHours(12))
        ->first();
    }else{
        dd('input value not found');
    }


    $rawPostData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    if($token)
    {
        if(isset($rawPostData['password'],$rawPostData['confirm_password']))
        {
            if($rawPostData['password'] === $rawPostData['confirm_password'])
            {
                $updatedUser = UserModel::where('id',$token->user_id)->first();
                $updatedUser->password = bcrypt($rawPostData['password']);
                $updatedUser->save();

                $data['status'] = 'success';
            }
            else
            {
                $data['status']='fail';
                $data['msg']='Password and Confirm Password Match failed.';
            }
         }
         else
         {
            $data['status']='fail';
            $data['msg']='Missing required paramater';
         }
    }
    else
    {
        $data['status']='fail';
        $data['msg']='Missing required paramater';
    }
      return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [the built in Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication)? Laravel handles all of this already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample from one of my own apps, which I'll talk you through:

```
 public function resetPassAction()
    {
        $email = $this->_request->getParam('email');
        $token = $this->_request->getParam('token');

        $user = $this->getUserService()->findUserByEmail($email);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception(UserException::USER_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        try {
            $link = $this->getUserService()->findEmailLink($email, $token);
        } catch (EmailLinkException $e) {
            $this->view->message = [$e->getMessage(), 'danger'];
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

        $form = new Application_Form_ResetPass();


        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

            if ($form->isValid($data)) {

                if ($data['password'] == $data['confirm']) {
                    $this->getUserService()->changePassword($user, $data['password']);
                    $this->getUserService()->deleteEmailLink($link);
                    $this->view->message = [' You have successfully changed your password.', 'success'];
                    $this->view->success = true;
                } else {
                    $this->view->message = $this->view->message = ['Passwords did not match, please try again.', 'danger'];
                    $this->view->form = $form;
                }
            } else {
                $this->view->form = $form;
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->form = $form;
        }
```

So we get the email address and token from the GET query, then find the user in the DB.

Then we find the "Email Link". This is just a row with a user id, token string, and expiry date. If the `findEmailLink()` method throws an exception, it's because the token wasn't found in the db, or had expired.

The code from the line `$form = //etc` is the actual change password code, which you needn't worry about.

Here's the actual findEmailLink() code:

```
public function findEmailLink($email, $token)
    {
        $link = $this->getEmailLinkRepository()->findByToken($token);
        if(!$link) {
            throw new EmailLinkException(EmailLinkException::LINK_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        if($link->getUser()->getEmail() != $email) {
            throw new EmailLinkException(EmailLinkException::LINK_NO_MATCH);
        }
        if($link->getExpiryDate() < new DateTime()) {
            throw new EmailLinkException(EmailLinkException::LINK_EXPIRED);
        }
        return $link;
    }
```

All this does is fetch it, check it matches the User's ID, and checks the expiry date is still in the future. If not, it throws the Exception, in which case you don't want to display your form!

I hope this helps you understand reset email flows!